# Android scrolling laggy

Tags: android, sqlite

I am making an android app using a video library. I have all the data in SQLite including the cover pictures. I used grid-view for the items but the scrolling is laggy. I am using view holder and I tried using glide but it's not helping and with Glide, it's even worse. Any ideas on how to make it work?

> The pictures are 404×285 pixels and stored in the SQLite Database

Comment: You can change you library glide to picasso https://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: U cant load byte with picasso, only urls

Comment: you can load byte array with Glide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it is really bad thing to save them in sql, you should save paths.

Second thing is you should load that picture size what is visible on the screen not shrinked. For that use loading library like Glide or Picasso.

Third use `RecyclerView` so your views would be recycled when they are not visible.

If you will follow these three things scrolling going to be smooth and nice :)

Comment: I use gridview with adapter doesn't it recycle the views?. And if I use path where can I store it? Internal sdcard?

Comment: You can use GridLayout with RecyclerView

Comment: RecyclerView is better but much more complex. anyway it works ty